# Making plots using loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, seurat

I created multiple vectors and plot them one-by-one. Now, I am trying to construct a loop to plot all vectors/data in one go.

I am trying to make list of all those vectors and then put that list in a for loop and save multiple plots separately.

Tried making a list and plotting all in one time.

```
library(seurat)

a=c("CCR7","SELL")
b=c("CCR7","IL7R","ITGB1","S100A4")
c=c("CD27","S100A4","RBMS3+","IL7R")
d=c("FOXP3","IL2RA","TIGIT")

FeaturePlot(cd4, a ,label = T,label.size = 6)+ scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")))
FeaturePlot(cd4, b,label = T,label.size = 6)+ scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")))
FeaturePlot(cd4,c,label = T,label.size = 6)+ scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")))
FeaturePlot(cd4, d,label = T,label.size = 6)+ scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "Spectral")))
```

Comment: So which approach did you try and got stuck with?